# Why do I have ' Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51' when I run 'mvn spring-boot:build-image'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I'm learning Docker and I'm trying to create an Image of my current Spring project.

I'm trying to run `mvn spring-boot:build-image` to create a docker image for my Spring Boot project, but I got this error when I execute it :

```
 Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.0:build-image (default-cli) on project dwh-webservices: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.0:build
-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51
```

I didn't find anything similar on the web, so I'm asking the question here.

Here is my `pom.xml`. If you need more, feel free to ask.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.business</groupId>
    <artifactId>dwh-webservices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DWH_WebServices</name>
    <description>DWH_WebServices</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue a few days ago.

The problem was that my company is rewriting the TSL certificate, so I was unable to download it :

```
Get "https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.10.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I had to add it manually. I follow [this](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot/issues/81) and it worked.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had a bug in my system where My Project SDK was Java 20 [image: IDE SDK Java v20],

but the dependency wasn't found for that Java version yet.
[image: Dependency not found for v20]

I had to set my IDE JDK to v17 (That's what was in my pom.xml release.version anyway) then I got past this issue.
[image: IDE SDK Java v17]
[image: I'm able to get past the original Error.]

Answer (score 3):

I have the same trouble even if I changed the sdk to 17. After I enforce the build to Java 17 writing like this, it works.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <image>
             <env>
                <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
             </env>
          </image>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are probably missing some dependencies,

Locate the dependencies you're missing, then install them manually, and build your project

add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-bindings</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

also, add this jar file [jar file](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.10.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar)

RightClick on your project > Maven > Reload project

I hope this will work, you can ping me any time

Comment: Why do I have this `Could not resolve dependencies for project com.business:dwh-webservices:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-bindings:jar:1.10.0 was not found in https ://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced` when I try to add the depency ? does it exist?

Comment: I was facing kind of the same issue, I tried this dependency and reloaded the Maven then the project was running good, I hope it should work with you too

Answer (score 0):

try by inserting this jar in your application :
https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.10.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Updating the DNS from auto -> manual and set it to 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 fixed the issue on windows.

Go to ->Network->Network and sharing center->click on connections->Properties->click on Internet Protocol version4(TCP/IPv4)->click on radio button  use the following dns server address automatically and set it to 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for creating docker image but different error code when executing this command  `mvn spring-boot:build-image`. I was getting this error:

> Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 145

I added following code in the pom.xml plugins tag:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

so my final plugin is now like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>dockerhubaccount/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                </image>
                <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I hope this will work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

add configurations in pom.xml . use this as reference. I changed all uppercase characters in artifactId to lowercase and  after adding all required dependencies and configurations , I restarted my system, then it's working in my system.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    <name>username/repository/ms-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                </image>
                <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not an expert but following a course, I have encountered kind of the same problem as yours.
I managed to create the docker image by adding this to the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
        <source>8</source>
        <target>8</target>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
```